# Change the name of [c#-nameof]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) is a C# keyword, but I don't see why the tag [c#-nameof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-nameof) should include the language, since it doesn't conflict with anything. So it should be renamed to just [nameof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nameof).

`NameOf` is also a VB.NET keyword (with the same meaning), so I think that's another reason why the tag should be renamed.

Comment: Sure.  Only 17 of them, just go for it.